# How to add new fields to a list in KeystoneJS

Tags: keystonejs

I want to extend the Blog in KeystoneJS by adding a boolean "frontPage" field to the Post schema, which I want to use to show selected posts on the homepage.

I came up with this code that I put in the updates folder:

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var async = require('async');

exports = module.exports = function (done) {
    let post = keystone.list('Post');

    post.add({
        frontPage: Boolean
    });
    done();
};
```

it seems to work, but the change does not persist when I restart the server. All docs describe the process of creating new Lists, but none tells how to modify an existing one. Also tried to add a `post.register()`at the end but no luck.

Is there a function to persist the new schema, or I should write a shell script outside Keystone for that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems to work, but the change does not persist when I restart the server.

Scripts in the [application `updates` folder](https://keystonejs.com/documentation/database/application-updates/) are intended for data import or migration, and intentionally are only applied once to a given deployment.

> All docs describe the process of creating new Lists, but none tells how to modify an existing one.

To add, remove, or change fields in your model you should modify the file in your Keystone project (eg: `models/Post.js`) and then restart your application to pick up the changes.

There generally is no need to create a corresponding `update` script unless you wanted to include associated data changes (for example, setting values for the existing documents).

Comment: That was much easier than I expected. Thank you @Stennie for your answer.
By the way, I'm wondering how does it work behind the scenes: when the model has a new field that was not present in the db schema, I suppose it gets added, but what if some time later I remove that field? I think this is related to how MongoDB/NOSQL databases work: new entries will not have that field, while previous entries with that field set will just remain as they are right?

Comment: @user3420936 Your expectation is correct: updating the declarative schema in Mongoose/Keystone does not affect any of the existing documents in your database. Keystone's application updates can be useful for one-off data actions like removing unused fields from documents or populating new fields with imported  values. The general behaviour of models & relationships is provided by [Mongoose schemas](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/guide.html). A Keystone List is a essentially a Mongoose schema with some additional UI annotations.